# how to execute a command with it's native gui using process builder

Tags: java, batch-file, processbuilder

```
            if(os.contains("windows"))
            {
                File bat = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA") + "/SelfCommandPrompt", appId + "-run.bat");
                bat.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                List<String> list = new ArrayList(1);
                list.add("@echo off");
                list.add("start" + " \"" + appName + "\" " + command);
                IOUtils.saveFileLines(list, bat, true);
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(bat.getAbsolutePath());
                //inherit IO and main directory
                pb.directory(getProgramDir());
                //fire the batch file
                pb.start();
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

So I dynamically create a .bat file and I want to run the process but, NOT IN THE BACKGROUND. Java forces the process to happen in the background how do I make it so it's not in the background? I am not looking to get the output stream from the .bat file I only want to execute it with the native gui it's intended to use on double click. Everywhere I look on these forums it only tells me how to do it in the background and get the outputstream? Why isn't there a boolean for this in the process builder? For my program specifically right now I want to reboot my java program with command prompt terminal on double click. I have the command generation working I tested the .bat file but, java again forces it to happen in the background.

Another use for doing a process not in the background. A java launcher for a game which executes a program with the gui not in the background which I may also need in the future.

Also the bat files output which is dynamically generated based off of the enviorment

```
java -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -cp C:\Users\jredfox\Documents\MDK\md5-spreadsheet\filededuper\bin;C:\Users\jredfox\Documents\MDK\md5-spreadsheet\filededuper\libs\apache-codecs.jar jredfox.selfcmd.SelfCommandPrompt true jredfox.filededuper.Main
```

**edit I figured out a command for windows but, only windows. I need commands for mac**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start" + " \"" + appName + "\" " + command);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "NOT IN THE BACKGROUND". Do you want a console window for the new process and/or want the new process to keep running after your main app exits?

Comment: I mean run with the gui aka command prompt terminal how is not in the background not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

- basically get the terminal string on linux you need to make an api for it
- save any shell scripts you need in the appdata
- make an api to get the app data folder
- create your custom command
- return if conditions are not met like the `System.console != null` for my thing yours will be different.
- execute command in new terminal window therefore the new native terminal using os commands.

All the code is found here.
https://github.com/jredfox/OpenTerminal